# How do I cancel a save in before_add association callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, exception, has-many, model-associations

I'm trying to cancel the save (gracefully) of a has_many element if is repeated. This is what I mean:

```
class AdmininstratorRole < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :permissions, before_add: :avoid_repetition

   def avoid_repetition(permission)
     raise "Repeated Permission" if self.permissions.where(klass: permission.klass, action: permission.action).count > 0
   end
end
```

If it wouldn't be an associated callback I could just return false and that would cancel the save. But since is an associated callback I need to raise an exception to cancel the saving as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). The problem is that I don't know how to recover gracefully from that exception.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception from whatever code is adding the permission role.

```
begin
  role.permissions.add(permission)
rescue
  # do whatever should happen here.
end
```

Although, you may want to check that the permission exists before trying to add it.